# Find all the functions $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(x+a)}{g(x+a)}$ for every $a$ in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials

My guess is that we are looking for functions of the form $\frac{f(x)}{cf(x)}$ where $f(x)\neq 0$   $\forall x \in\mathbb{Q} $, $c\in \mathbb{Q}^*$.

Indeed  $\frac{f(x)}{cf(x)}=\frac{f(x+a)}{cf(x+a)}=\frac{1}{c}$

How can I prove that those are the only ones?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f(x)/g(x)$ are not functions and $\mathbb Q[x]$ does not contain functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pick some $b \in {\mathbb Q}$ for which $g(b) \neq 0$ and evaluate at $x = b$. That gives $f(a) / g(a) = f(b) / g(b)$ for all $a \in {\mathbb Q}$. Letting $c = f(b) / g(b)$, that means $f(a) = c g(a)$ for all $a \in {\mathbb Q}$. Therefore also, as elements of ${\mathbb Q}[x]$, $f(x) = c g(x)$, as you suspected.